# Construct a loop over function, and apply does not work.

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm very new to R, I want to run a specific function (ideal from the pscl package) for 50 different data (roll call class) that have a suffix from 1 to 50, and I want to save the results in objects also with a 1 to 50 suffix, but I can not do it.

The apply does not work, since I need to specify additional paramaters in the ideal function, and I already tried creating a new function that sets the additional parameters and permits to specify the function only with the data, but it fails in the second step (does not recognize the object).

I have the data objects for my function: rc.1, rc.2, ..., rc.50
And try to do the following - following closely how I would do it in Stata...

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    est.leg[i]<-ideal(rc[i], maxiter=1000, burnin=500, thin=10, normalize=TRUE)
}
```

And it does not evaluate in rc[i], says "object 'rc' not found"

I have also tried:

```
loop.ideal<- function(zz){ 
   ideal(zz, d=1, maxiter=100, burnin=50, thin=10, normalize=TRUE)
}
```

but when testing the function, it does not work with the iterations.

I would really appreciate any help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It will be hard for anyone to help unless you provide a *reproducible* example that others can run on their own machines. This would include a small subset of your data (using `dput()`)...

Comment: To joran's point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I think lapply, as suggested by Joris, is the way. But you will likely have to wait a long time running ideal 50 times. Especially if the data is not so small. Couldn't you run it in parallel?

Comment: @joran, do you have this comment in a text file so you cut & paste it easily?  You should ...

Comment: @Manoel: following @Joris's solution below, if you are on a multicore Mac or Linux machine you can just `library(multicore); mclapply(...)`

Comment: @Ben Bolker - See [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/pro-forma-comments). So, yes. ;)

Comment: @joran : Thank you very much! Works like a charm, that script.

Answer (score 7):

As Gavin says.

You can loop over the names of your objects, like :

```
object.names <- paste("rc",1:50,sep=".")
```

Better is to learn to work with lists. You can make a list of the objects by using `lapply`

```
object.list <- lapply(object.names,get)
```

This one will use the function `get` on every name on the list with names. lapply returns a list, so you have a list of the objects.

If the function is correct, you can then use the same trick again for the `ideal` function :

```
est.leg <- lapply(object.list,ideal , maxiter=1000, burnin=500, 
                  thin=10, normalize=TRUE)
```

This should give the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* pass extra arguments to `apply()`, see the `...` argument in `?apply`. If what you write is correct, you don't have objects `rc[i]`, you have `rc.i` where `i` is actually an integer. `[` is for subsetting an object, so your code is asking for the `i`th component of the `rc` object. You seem to be wanting to retrieve the object with name `rc.i` with `i` replaced by an integer.

Without knowing more about `rc` etc, you can try `get(paste("rc.", i, sep = ""))` in place of `rc[i]`.